# Classic ASP Regular Expressions

Tags: regex, validation, asp-classic, user-input

I am trying to validate a querystring coming from an email activation link, written in Classic ASP.

The querystring input contains numbers, letters and 2 forward slashes. Like this: **`G3hEus87YK/6738/HE347sxThH`** and I need to validate it, checking that only numbers, letters and slashes have been used.

The numbers in between the slashes could be 1-9 digits long, here I used 4 as an example but there are always 10 alphanumerical characters before the slash and 10 after.

I have done this so far, that will run the check, but I'm not sure which pattern to give it!

```
Function validateToken(token) 
  Set regEx = New RegExp 
  regEx.IgnoreCase = True
  regEx.Pattern = "???????????" 
  validateToken = regEx.Test(Trim(Request.QueryString("token"))) 
End Function
```

My attempt for numbers and letters only would be, `[A-z][0-9]` , but looking for 2 slashes confuses me. How can I look for slashes too?

I suppose if I wrote the pattern in pure English, it would read:

- 10 alphanumerical characters, any case.
- A forward slash
- Numbers, 1-9 digits long
- A forward slash
- 10 alphanumerical characters, any case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"there are always 10 alphanumerical characters before the slash and 10 after"*

Ten alphanumerical characters are `[a-z\d]{10}`, assuming that `IgnoreCase` is enabled.

> *"The numbers in between the slashes could be 1-9 digits long"*

That would be `\d{1,9}`,  so the final pattern is fairly simple:

```
regEx.Pattern = "^[a-z\d]{10}/\d{1,9}/[a-z\d]{10}$"
```

The `^` and `$` disallow anything before or after the pattern.

Comment: "^[a-z\d]{10}/\d{1,9}/[a-z\d]{10}$"
This pattern wont allow any capital alphabet, so please consider it, thanks

Comment: @Md.EliasHossain This is nonsense. Read my answer again, and look at his code.

Comment: Oh! Yes I understand that you assumed IgnoreCase is enabled, I'm very sorry and pardon me please, thanks for your valuable time.

Comment: @MdEliasHossain: No need to apologize. ;-)

Comment: i'm new on regEx and asp. The character \d what it means?

Answer (score 1):

Please try with below expression:

```
^(([A-z\d]{10})/(\d{1,9})/([A-z\d]{10}))$
```